# How to access the global component and local component from inside an event handler of the local component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components: GlobalComp & LocalComp.

eventHandler is assigned to LocalComp's onEvent prop.

How can I access both GlobalComp & LocalComp from inside eventHandler's execution context?

Comment: maybe with [redux](http://redux.js.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Set the onclick to `someFunction(this)` such that `someFunction` calls variable `this`. This will basically make the element on click pass itself to the function and then the function can get the element by using `this` as a variable.